# R: summing up daily data into weekly data

Tags: r

I have a large data file of stock data.

I have organized it by ticker and data:

```
Ticker   Date        Vol.
A        20050501     23
A        20050502     45
AB       20050501    100
AV       20050503    100
BC       20050501     50
```

How would I group and sum the data into weekly volume while still keeping the same alphabetical and date format? For example, summing 23 and 45 and putting an entry that would be as below:

```
A    20050501  68
AB   20050501  100
```

I would want to list all the weekly sums of volume for A, followed by all the weekly sums for AB, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `lubridate` and `dplyr`:

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
Ticker<-rep(c("a","b","c"),6)
Vol.<-rnorm(18,100,100)
Date<-c("20050501","20050502","20050503","20050504","20050505","20050506","20050507","20050508","20050509",
         "20050510","20050511","20050512","20050513","20050514","20050515","20050516","20050517","20050518")
dat<-data.frame(Ticker,Date,Vol.)
dat$Date<-ymd(dat$Date)
dat$Week<-week(dat$Date)
dat_summary<-dat%>%
  group_by(Week,Ticker)%>%
  summarize(sumweek=sum(Vol.))

dat_summary
#Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
#Groups: Week

#  Week Ticker   sumweek
#1   18      a 296.88270
#2   18      b 251.31511
#3   18      c  16.43714
#4   19      a 218.20407
#5   19      b 425.01059
#6   19      c 314.51562
#7   20      a 133.38258
#8   20      b -23.08902
#9   20      c 406.87671
```

if you have more than one year in your data, then you will want to create a "year column" `dat$Year<-year(dat$Date)` and then group by "week and year" `group_by(Week,Year,Ticker)` .

Comment: I'm looking to still keep the data grouped by ticker and summing up the individual weekly data for that ticker. So I want to sum up data for each week I have for ticker A and list all each week on consecutive rows. Then sum up each week for the next ticker, and the next.

Comment: edited you can just `group_by(Week,Ticker)` and if you have more than one year remember to add a year column so it is `group_by(Week,Ticker,Year)`

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I got it to work but my week is only summing through Thursday. How can I switch my week to make it run Sunday-Saturday instead of Friday-Thursday? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use the `difftime` function to find the number of weeks from an arbitrary start point to the day in question. where `first_sunday` is the date of the first sunday in your sample you can create a column `dat$diffweek<-floor(difftime(dat$Date,first_sunday,units="weeks"))`

Comment: Another quick question. I have my week set now. Is there some way I can now list the first date (Sunday) of the specific week if I have data for it. For example, Week 17 corresponds to Sunday 05/01/2005. Is there some way for week 17 I can list 20050501 in a column, and if I had data for week 18 I would list 20050508, etc.?

Comment: sure it's the same `group_by()` syntax with `min(day)` instead of `sum()`